# Does this electric panel meet code and does the wiring from it meet NEC standards

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I have an apartment building, with a panel that supplies 2 different apartments.

Breaker #15 supplies all electricity to 2 bedrooms and a living room including lighting and electric outlets.

Breaker #2 supplies 1 bedroom, bathroom, and kitchen (*kitchen has gas stove*). The service to this panel is 100 amps.

**Questions:**

- 1. Does this panel meet current electrical code standards?
- 2. If it does not meet code, can I simply replace it with a code conforming panel or must I rewire all the wires going from each breaker to the electric outlets & lighting fixtures upstairs (*something that I am trying to avoid because of the extensive cost*). This panel is in the basement, and the apartments that it powers are on the 1st and 2nd floors.
- 3. Does the current electric code limit how many rooms can be supplied by a single circuit breaker. In other words must I run additional wires upstairs to the 2nd floor or is the #2 and #15 breaker setup enough to pass code inspection? This is a rental, thus I am trying to avoid excessive repairs and remodeling due to budget constraints.

[image: Main Panel]

Comment: You might want to consider putting a sub-panel in each apartment; that keeps most of the re-wiring in the apartment, and also means the tenants don't need to access the basement or call the landlord for minor trips.

Comment: FYI rental == you must hire a licensed electrician. You cannot legally DIY rental electrical work in the vast majority of jurisdictions.

Comment: Which rooms are in which apartments?

Comment: I suspect the lugs on the top of the buses (above breakers 1&2) may not be listed for two wires. Look for permitted size and quantities on the panel cover or etched on the lugs themselves..

Answer (score 6):

There's a concept called *grandfathering* which says **If the work was legal on the day it was installed, then when Code changes *later*, it's still legal.** You're not required to  tear out a bunch of wiring every 3 years when Code is revised.

This gets into a lot of lawyering about *when* the work was done and what was legal *then*.  However we can safely pass judgment on things that were never legal.

There are at least 3 panels in this building.   If you look on the "main lugs" above the breakers, you see 2 wires tapped onto those lugs.

- One set comes from another location containing a main breaker or main panel, which presumably limits current on these wires to 100A.
- Then you have this panel, of course.
- Then the other set of wires goes onward to yet another panel.

Those wires are not service wires.  A service is what comes in straight off the meter.  Once it's past the main breaker, it is **feeder**.   And both panels - this and the next - share that 100A of feeder.  Daisy chaining panels like this is *legal*, except for...

---

**The most obvious code violation is the double-tapping of those main lugs**.  Can't do it. Those 2 wires need to go into a 3-void Polaris connector, then a same-size pigtail needs to come down to the lugs so there is only 1 wire per lug.

Your subpanel doesn't have any ground bar, but that's not unusual when you have a panel that is connected entirely with metal conduit or armored cable, since that metal shell covers the need for grounds.  I do see one ground wire that some epsilon-minus put on the neutral bar; that's not OK and must be dealt with.

---

To your questions:

**#1. Does it meet current Code standards?**  *It doesn't have to.  It's grandfathered.*

**#2. Can I simply change a nonconforming panel?** You wouldn't need to *change* the panel; unless you smuggled it in from a third world country, surely the panel is legal stock.  You might have to correct defects, like the double-tapped lugs.

**#3. Does NEC limit number of rooms per breaker?**  Not as you'd think.  NEC 2020 has requirements for a number of dedicated circuits.  2 dedicated kitchen receptacle circuits.  Dishwasher. Disposal. Built-in microwave.  1 dedicated bathroom recep circuit. 1 dedicated laundry room circuit.   Almost all of them are GFCI or AFCI, and the AFCI must be done at the breaker, **unless the route to the first receptacle is in metal conduit**.

I don't understand why you're saying that the work has to come up to modern Code.  It doesn't.  The only exception is if the work was done illegally (i.e. without a permit), at which point the city is at liberty to make you tear out all the illegal work (even if there is nothing wrong with it) and then make you pull a permit to re-do the work properly.  Since the permit would be this year, this year's Code would apply.

Lastly, as you have been cautioned, **a landlord cannot DIY electrical on a rental unit.  All work must be done by a licensed electrician.** It really doesn't matter what your financial situation is; you just can't do it.   That law is to prevent landlords from doing inferior work that puts others' lives in danger.  The logic is an owner-occupant has incentive to do the job properly: a landlord only has incentive to do the work as cheaply as possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems here. Assuming the work met code when done, they may not be active problems, but certainly not to current codes.

Item the first - Apartments, plural - fine if landlord is paying electric bill, not fine otherwise. If tenants pay for electricity, you need a separate metered service for each tenant  plus a separate metered service for common areas, paid by the landlord.

Current code would require re-wiring, since you need two 20A circuits for countertop outlets in the kitchen, and one 20A circuit for the bathroom (for **each** apartment, not shared with other uses) and at least one more (depends on square footage) for other outlets and lighting.

So that is a minimum of 8 circuits, 6 of which must be 20A for two apartments, and more may be required depending on the size of the apartments.

Current code also requires AFCIs and/or GFCIs on most circuits.

On the plus side, most of the wiring is in conduit.